# Calling function in external process without detours (Windows)

Tags: c++, function, process, external

i would like to call a function with my args, which exists in external process. I know func name, expected args and address. I would like to do it by injecting my dll, and then controll external process with commands sent by named pipe.

I have found a way how to call a function, but it uses detours. How to call a function without detours?

Thanks, M

Comment: What do you want to do DLL injection for?

Comment: what is the actual problem? inject a dll and call that function

Comment: Thats why i asked. Becouse i dont know how to do that ;>

Comment: Find out entry point address of this function, push arguments to stack and call the proc with appropriate assembler commands